# $p$ is a limit point of a sequence $\{p_n\}$ iff $\forall \epsilon>0,$ there is infinitely many points satisfaying $d(p_k,p)<\epsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, metric-spaces, self-learning

There is something wrong with a homework exercise that was given to me about limit points.

***Def***. We say that a point $p$ in a metric space $(E,p)$ is a **limit point** of a sequence $\{p_n\}$ if $p \notin \{p_n\}$ and there is a subsequence $\{p_{n_k}\}$ such that $p_{n_k} \rightarrow p$.

It was given to me to prove the following result.

> **Exercise**. Show that $p$ is a limit point of a sequence $\{p_n\}$ iff $\forall \epsilon>0,$ there is infinitely many $k \in \mathbb{N}$
>   satisfaying $d(p_k,p)<\epsilon$.

---

**My attempt**

$(\rightarrow)$ By the definition of limit point, there is a subsequence $\{p_{n_k}\}$ in $\{p_n\}\setminus \{p\}$ so that, given $\epsilon>0, \exists K\in \mathbb{N}: \forall k>K, 0<d(p_{n_k},p)<\epsilon$. It clearly implies that $d(p_k,p)<\epsilon$ for infinitely many points of $\{p_n\}$.

My problem is with the other direction. I can see the existence of convergent subsequence(s) to $p$, but I am not able to show that $p$ is not in this (these) subsequences. If I choose a constant sequence, the statement does not hold. It means that it cannot be shown.

It would be correct if he had stated:

" $p$ is a limit point of a sequence $\{p_n\}$ iff $\forall \epsilon>0,$ there is infinitely many $k \in \mathbb{N}$ satisfaying $0<d(p_k,p)<\epsilon$".

What do you think?

---

**UPDATE**
Having accpted the exercise is wrong, a new question arose.

Suppose, given $\epsilon>0$, infinitely many points satisfy $0<d(p_k,p)<\epsilon$ and denote the set of these indices $k$ by $I$. Clearly, $\{p_k\}_{k\in I}$ is a subsequence of $\{p_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ and $p\notin \{p_k\}_{k\in I}$. But what guarantees that $p\notin \{p_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$, which is our aim?

As long as I know, for arbitrary metric spaces, the limit point need not to be unique. Furthermore, the sequence $\{p_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ need not to be convergent. It may be the case, in addition to impose $0<d(p_k)<\epsilon$, to suppose $x\notin \{p_n\}$, to prove $(\leftarrow)$.

Any ideas?

Comment: Oh... I see your point.  The statement as given is simply false.  Having infinitely many $0\le d(p_k, p) < \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon$ does *not* imply it is a limit point.  But having infinitely many $0 < d(p_k,p) < \epsilon$ does.  The text carelessly didn't consider the option of infinitely many $p_k = p$.  The text is wrong... you are right.

Answer (score 3):

If you want that $p$ is not an element of the sequence you need to add, $0<d(p,p_n)<\epsilon$ otherwise you can take the constant sequence $p_n=p$.

You can take $\epsilon={1\over n}$ this insures the existence of infinite  and (at least) an element  $p_n$ such that $d(p,p_n)<{1\over n}$. This implies that $p$ is a limit point.

Comment: But how can I ensure that $p\neq p_n$? By the definition above, $p \notin \{p_n\}$. I understand the existence of convergent subsequence(s) to $p$, but I'm not able to show that this subsequence does not contain $p$.

Comment: Actually, the text made an error.  As Tsemo Aristide points out you must add the condition that for any $\epsilon$ there are infinitely many $0 < d(p, p_n) < \epsilon$ and not *just* $d(p; p_n) < \epsilon$.  The text took it as a given that the $p_n \ne p$.  Obviously you can make an infinite sequence of $p_k =p$ and that will satisfy that an infinite number of $d(p,d_n) = 0 < \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon$.  So the statement is just plain wrong and your objection is correct.

Comment: @fleablood A new question just arose. Suppose, given $\epsilon>0$, infinitely many points satisfy $0<d(p_k,p)<\epsilon$ and denote the set of these indices $k$ by $I$. Clearly, $\{p_k\}_{k\in I}$ is a subsequence of $\{p_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ and $p\notin \{p_k\}_{k\in I}$. But what guarantees that $p\notin \{p_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$, which is our aim?

Comment: If $d(p_k, p) \ne 0$ then $p_k \ne p$.  You have infinitely many of these for any $\epsilon$.  Take and infinite number of $\epsilon_k$ so that $\epsilon_{k} < \epsilon_{k-1}$ (example let $\epsilon_k = \frac 1k$) and then as there are infinite $p_i$ where $0< d_(p_i,p) < \epsilon$  pick any one of these where the index $i$ is greater then the index of $p_{n_{k-1}}$ and call that $p_{n_k}$.  Thus it's easy to show $p_{n_k}\to p$ and $p_{n_k} \ne 0$.

Comment: @fleablood I understand that there is a subsequence which converges to $p$. As I mentioned above, such a point $p$ is a limit point of the subsequence $\{p_k\}_{k \in I}$, i.e., $\{p_k\}_{k \in I} \rightarrow p$ and $p$ is a limit point of $\{p_k\}_{k \in I}$. This is clear to me. But It remains to prove that $p$ is a limit point of $\{p_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, i.e., $p \notin \{p_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$. The fact that $p \notin \{p_k\}_{k \in I}$ implies $p \in \{p_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ or $p \in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{p_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$.

Comment: @fleablood *Correction: The fact that $p \notin \{p_k\}_{k \in I}$ implies $p \in \{p_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ or $p \in E\setminus \{p_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$. My point is that I don't think it is possible to show that $p \notin \{p_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ only with we have assumed. So the need of additional hypothesis. "$\forall \epsilon>0$, there is infinitely many points such that $0<d(p_k,p)<\epsilon$ and $p\notin \{p_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$"

Comment: @fleablood The fact that a subsequence converges to $p$ does not seem to imply that this point is a limit point of the sequence (under the definition that I gave above).

Comment: The excercise assumes that $p\ne p_n$ for any $n$.  Admittedly the excercise should have *explicitely* stated that but as your definition is of t limit point is that no point of the sequence is equal to the limit that requirment for the sequence is obvious.  BUt that seems like a weird definition.  So according to that definition.  $1$ is not the limit point of $1, \frac 12,\frac 34, \frac 78,.......$ because $1$ is in the sequence.  That does not jibe with my idea of a limit point.

Comment: Okay, I can not find a *single* source that defines limit point as you have put it.  Every definition I know says that $p$ is a limit point of $\{p_n\}$ if there is a subsequence $\{p_{n_k}\}$ so that no $p_{n_k} = p$ and $\{p_{n_k}\}\to p$.  (Or a topological equivalence).

Comment: @fleablood In your definition, the exercise would be done! Unfortunately, I suspect my professor gave (again) a wrong definition. Note that in the direction $(\leftarrow)$, the exercise assumes only that infinitely many $k\in \mathbb{N} $ satisfies $p\neq p_k$, and not $p\neq p_k \forall k \in \mathbb{N}$. See the difference? So, this $p$ could be in $\{p_k\}_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ which is what I don't want.

Comment: @fleablood To clear this point, the set $I$ of indices $k$ satisfying $p\neq p_k$ is an infinite subset of $\mathbb{N}$, which does not imply that $I$ is the whole set of natural numbers itself. It means that it is possible that for some index $i \in \mathbb{N}, p=p_i$ where $p_i \notin \{p_k\}_{k\in I}$ but  $p_i \in \{p_k\}_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$. If it occurs, then $p$ is not a limit point of ${p_k\}_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ under the above definition.

Comment: @fleablood In any case, I should work with this definition, and point out where the exercise's statement fails. In my opinion, the proof in the direction $(\leftarrow)$ can be proved if it were assumed $p\notin \{p_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$